# How do I split a list into uneven sized chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so I have not really seen this be done before but I want to split a list that contains consecutive duplicate elements in such a way that these elements are kept together and every chunk contains 4 unique elements.

suppose I have the following list:

`letters = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H']`

I want to split this list into uneven sized chunks based on the uniqueness of the elements, i.e. :

```
[['A','A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H']]
```

So every list contains 4 letter sequences and need not be of the same length. In addition the chunks overlap on one letter in such a way that consecutive duplicate letters are not split but kept together.

EDIT: a list that contains some duplicate letters that are not consecutive like `['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D']` would be split like this: `chunks = [ ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B'], ['B', 'C', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'B', 'C', 'D'] ]`

Comment: Well, that is something that have to be coded up. :-)
Luckly it is simple enough someone will do that for you, before someone else decide to close the question because it is asking for something from the ground up, not a question about existing code.

It is doable with regular `for` and `if` statements, though

Comment: [meta] on the value of _not_ closing questions like this: I think these provide a needed space for begginer/intermediate users to contribute and feel great about their exercise, and is welcoming for everyone involved.

Comment: Yes, please show your attempt even if it produces wrong output.

Comment: In fact, show your attempt especially if it does produce wrong output. Understanding what you tried, what your input was, what your output was and what you expected your output to be is sort of the essential four sides of the question square, and how SO can be most useful to you!

Comment: I think the question has merit beyond just homework. "N-sized overlapping chunks ignoring duplicates" is the kind of thing I search all the time to see if anybody has an elegant solution.

Comment: What should happen for `letters = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H']`? (I swapped an A with the B.)

Comment: @KellyBundy Good question, I suppose it slipped my mind when dealing with the specific example mentioned in my original question but I added some clarification in the edit about the case where some letters are duplicates but not consecutive.

Comment: Then your description is wrong, since for example `['B', 'C', 'B', 'C']` doesn't have "4 unique letters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is homework, treat the solution below as a spoiler. It's quite a fun problem, don't miss the chance of trying to solve it yourself!

Here's one possible solution: by grouping all repeated letters, the chunks are now equal sized and easy to create. Then we just "chain" all repeats in a chunk together to match the format you want.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

letters = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H']

repeats = [list(group) for letter, group in groupby(letters)]
print(repeats)
# [['A', 'A'], ['B'], ['C', 'C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['F'], ['G'], ['H', 'H']]

chunks = [list(chain(*repeats[i:i+4])) for i in range(len(repeats)-3)]
print(chunks)
# [['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H']]
```

Edit: note the bug pointed by Alain T. below, where sequences like ABAB are miscounted as having 4 unique items. If your dataset contains sequences like that, and you need 4 *unique* letters per chunk, his solution is more correct.

Comment: If you have a duplicate letter that is not consecutive (e.g. `['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D']`), this will produce a group with fewer than 4 distinct letters (`[...,['B', 'C', 'B', 'C'],...]`)

Comment: @AlainT. Good comment, this case slipped my mind initially. I added some clarification in the eddited question.

Comment: @Magnus Then this solution works for your problem, but maybe you should edit the question to avoid the word "unique". You seem to want chunks of 4 "letter sequences".

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is using a start position for grouping and a Counter for tracking  distinct letters in the queue.  When adding a letter, check the counter to see if the letter makes the counter exceed its 4 letter limit.  If it does, output the current group (from start) and remove letters, advancing start of the group until one letter goes away:

```
from collections import Counter

letters = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H']

counts    = Counter()            # count of each letter in current group
distinct  = 0                    # number of distinct letters
start     = 0                    # start index of current group
result    = []
for i,c in enumerate(letters):
    counts[c] += 1                # add to letter counts
    distinct += counts[c] == 1    # count new distinct letter
    if distinct > 4:                    # if exceed 4 letters
        result.append(letters[start:i]) # output current group
        while distinct > 4:
            x = letters[start]          # move start of group 
            start += 1                  # removing letters
            counts[x] -= 1              # until count below threshold
            distinct  -= not counts[x]
if distinct == 4:
    result.append(letters[start:])      # add last group if 4 letters in it


print(result)

[['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
 ['C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H']]
```

Alternatively you could go through all subscripts of the grouped (consecutive) letters and pick the ones that have 4 distinct letters.  It would be less code but a lot less efficient:

```
from itertools import groupby,chain

groups = [ g for _,(*g,) in groupby(letters) ]
result = [ list(chain(*groups[s:e+1]))
           for s in range(len(groups)) for e in range(s,len(groups))
           if len(set().union(*groups[s:e+1]))==4 ]

print(result)
[['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H']]
```

Answer (score 1):

First find the boundary indices, them use the to slice:

```py
n = len(letters)
I = 0, *(i for i in range(1, n) if letters[i] != letters[i-1]), n
chunks = [letters[i:j] for i, j in zip(I, I[4:])]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZFLCsIwEIZxm1OMqyaSgoILEbrwbc9QshBJbVTSUFNQF17EjRs9lKcxj7Yi6uaDzEz-fx7XhzrpLJe3273UaTh4ti57rjUvDhBBEowCCh5ji0mDqcXMYm6xsFh6MMSPiq-1FXAKfwQYNQa_ZV3qt5lLfbm76J92GELS9LLnElejERSbQJdCBwtI8wIECAnFSm447lGQBEQKVW0iGLSj9yvsMWJK0Dor5c4tqUkNt8yrUdhawbNQOKYQJ_0hI6YLVQipcf0xAr8m8hEn_gzVNeqrvAA)